# Regex to extract a data in multi line string containing sections

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a below multi line string which has various section,

```
sample='''

GigabetI/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
    keep alive set
        internet address 10.10.10.2
LoopBack0 is up, line protocol is up
        keep alive is not set
    internet address 10.10.10.3
Tunnel12 is up, line protocol is up
        keep alive is set
        internet address 10.10.10.12
TenGigabetI/0/0/2 is up, line protoco is up
        keep alive is set
        internet addresss is 192.12.168.1 '''
```

my expected output will be a list of dictionary

```
d=[{'interface':'GigabetI/0/0/1','IP':'10.10.10.2'},{'interface':'LoopBack0','IP':'10.10.10.3'},{'interface':'Tunnel12 ','IP':'10.10.10.12'},{'interface':'TenGigabetI/0/0/2 ','IP':'192.12.168.1'}]
```

I need a separate dictionary for each section, but i failed to extract data in this section output

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using `re.finditer` with named capture groups:

```py
import re

sample = "GigabetI/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up keep alive set internet address 10.10.10.2 LoopBack0 is up, line protocol is up keep alive is not set internet address 10.10.10.3 Tunnel12 is up, line protocol is up keep alive is set internet address 10.10.10.12 TenGigabetI/0/0/2 is up, line protoco is up keep alive is set internet addresss is 192.12.168.1"
r = re.compile('(?P<interface>\S+).*?(?P<IP>\d(?:\.\d+){3})')
d = [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(sample)]
print(d)
```

This prints:

```
[{'interface': 'GigabetI/0/0/1', 'IP': '0.10.10.2'},
 {'interface': 'LoopBack0', 'IP': '0.10.10.3'},
 {'interface': 'Tunnel12', 'IP': '0.10.10.12'},
 {'interface': 'TenGigabetI/0/0/2', 'IP': '2.12.168.1'}]
```